# Programmatically setting property value on array item in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have an application that uses Polymer. In this application, I have a component that looks like this:

**my-component.html**

```
<dom-module id="view-tests">
    <template>
      <table>
        <tbody>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ items }}" as="item">              
              <tr>
                <td>[[ item.name ]]</td>
                <td><item-status status="[[ item.status ]]"></item-status></td>
              </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button on-click="bindClick">Bind</button>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: "my-component",
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  new Item({ name:'Item 1', status:'In Stock' }),
                  new Item({ name:'Item 2', status:'Sold Out' })
                ];
              }  
            },
          },

          bindClick: function() {
            var items = items;              
            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
              if (i === 1) {
                items[i].status = 'In Stock';
              }
            }
          }          
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As shown in the code snippet above, there is another component `item-status`.

**item-status.html**

```
<dom-module id="test-status">
    <template>
        <span class$="{{ statusClass }}">{{ status }}</span>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "item-status",
            properties: {
                status: {
                    type: String,
                    value: '',
                    observer: '_statusChanged'
                }               
            },

            _statusChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === 'In Stock') {
                  this.statusClass = 'green';
                } else if (newValue === 'Sold Out') {
                  this.statusClass = 'red';
                } else {
                  this.statusClass = 'black';
                }
            }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

The initial data-bindings work correctly. However, when I click the "Bind" button, the text does not update as I would expect. In addition, the text color does not change like I was expecting. I have that `var items = items;` intentionally because in my real code, there is a call back happening and I have to pass items into the callback. I'm not sure if there's a better way. Still, my view is not updating properly.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. when I click the "Bind" button, the text does not update as I would expect

For this to work, you have to use this.set('item.1.status', 'In Stock'). Please read https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding for more details on array binding.

> 2. In addition, the text color does not change like I was expecting.

You are just setting the class. You have to style the item. Include style tag in your item-status as below

```
<style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }
      .green {
        color: green;
      }
</style>
```

> 3.I have that var items = items; intentionally because in my real code, there is a call back happening

I don't think you can set values to array items in callbacks and make the polymer observers work. If you post more details on your scenario someone might help you.

4. It is good practice to have your dom-module id and your Polymer 'is' id the same. This is the first instance I am encountering different ids and I am almost sure it will break something.

The working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yugofo/edit?html,console,output